# Advice: Send E-mails at User-Selected Times Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendmessage

This is more advice as the method I was thinking to solve this problem isn't elegant. My use case is simple. A user can select any given DATE and TIME, that an e-mail will need to be sent from the system.

For example: A user can select he wants his e-mail to be sent to him at 7:31 am every Monday Wed and Friday from the Ruby on Rails System.

Assume there are going to be 1000+ users on the machine; Is the only way this will work is to run a cron job via rake every second, and check to see if if the time is equal to the time of any user who matches the specific TIME and Day?

That seems idiotic, but then I might just be an elegant idiot. What would you use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner solution than relying on CRON would be to rely on a messaging queue to store scheduled jobs and a bunch of independent processes to process them. This also scales pretty well beyond a single machine and into millions of users.

Check out [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) or [delayed_job_recurring](https://github.com/amitree/delayed_job_recurring) paired with [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

Resque/sidekiq use redis queue for storing jobs, delayed_job uses your database. For 1000+ users either is fine, for higher loads in-memory queue like redis would be a better choice.